# Python - Django - How to handle a multiple page form correctly

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an application that is used to store vehicle information. I created a Vehicle Model which has many foreign keys including a Consumption Model, Capacity Model, Tires Model, Fuel Model etc.

Multiple Page Form:

When a user wants to add a vehicle to the inventory I wanted to use a multiple page form to break up the steps. So, for example, the first step would be the Vehicle modelform and the second step would be the Fuel modelform. The problem I am running into is storing modelforms over multiple pages without using formwizard.

My Thoughts:

There seems to be no information on how to do this, am I the only one who wants to do this or is the solution blatantly obvious? In other languages I would have stored all the forms in a session and saved them at the end of the process. It seems you can't store a modelform in a session because I get a pickling error (unless I serialize it perhaps?) so I assume that is a no-no. I could save the modelform of a given page to the database before going to the next step but that has multiple issues. i.e. what if the user stops halfway through?

Any explanation on the normal way this is done, or if it is ok to serialize modelforms would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the form wizard:

> Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in hashed HTML  fields so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.
>
> You might want to use this if you have
>   a lengthy form that would be too
>   unwieldy for display on a single page.
>   The first page might ask the user for
>   core information, the second page
>   might ask for less important
>   information, etc.

More details in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but I wanted to avoid the form wizard because I have images that need to be upload in the form. I also specified in my initial question that I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Justin, sorry I missed that wizard part. To avoid pickling errors, I think you can pickle the form's fields individually instead of the form.